# Importing and parsing a TSV file with Python

Tags: python

Ok... so I am trying to build a python script that would allow me to import a TSV file into a matrix. Then take the first three columns.. col-1 is day, 2 is minTemp and 3 is maxTemp. I want to grab the minTemp from col2 along with the correlating day and maxTemp along with the correlating day. This is from a NOAA file. So there is website information etc at the top, and the actual data I want to pull begins with a tab on line 9. Can't figure out how to get a correlating day. I am also getting errors out the wazoo with this one. I have not touched Python in two years so please forgive me.

```
import csv 
inFile = 'weather1.txt'
with open(inFile,'r') as tsv:
    for i in range (8): 
        inFile.next()
    weatherOutput = [line.strip().split('\t') for line in tsv];
    for row in WeatherOutput:
        weatherOutput.append(row);
        print (WeatherOutput)
    day = (col[1])
    maxTemp = (col[2])
    minTemp = (col[3]);
    minimumTemp = min(col[3])
    maximumTemp = max(col[2])
    print (minimumTemp, maximumTemp);
```

Comment: If your data is structured consider using the pandas library, you can load your data into a dataframe and then calculate all the information you need

Comment: Why do you `import`, but never use, `csv`? What does *"errors out the wazoo"* mean (please provide traceback)? Where do you think `col` comes from?

Comment: That would be helpful to have a traceback of the errors and may at least the relevant part of the input file you're trying to parse.

Comment: Some of the errors that I am getting include. An attribute error for infile.next()"str object has no read(). I also came across an EOL error while parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You have already split into a list of list do zip to transpose the list:

```
weather = [["monday",22,10],["tuesday",25,9]]

days, maxTemps ,minTemps = zip(*weather)
print (days, maxTemps, minTemps)
('monday', 'tuesday') (22, 25) (10, 9)
```

indexing also starts a `0` not `1` so if you were trying to access the first three elements it would be `col[0],col[1] and col[2]`

Appending to the list you are iterating over will mean the list keeps growing the so you will loop indefinitely and your code will never go any further:

```
   for row in WeatherOutput:
        weatherOutput.append(row);
        print (WeatherOutput)
```